LuaU - Need to make this efficient, don't want to spam elseifs
Okay, so, I'm just curious on how to make this more efficent. I know it likely has something to do with a table loop like in pairs() or something. I know this is bad code, and I want to find a way to make it not bad.
if string.find(subject.Name, 0) then
    inVal.Value = 0
elseif string.find(subject.Name, 1) then
    inVal.Value = 1
elseif string.find(subject.Name, 2) then
    inVal.Value = 2
elseif string.find(subject.Name, 3) then
    inVal.Value = 3
elseif string.find(subject.Name, 4) then
    inVal.Value = 4
elseif string.find(subject.Name, 5) then
    inVal.Value = 5
elseif string.find(subject.Name, 6) then
    inVal.Value = 6
elseif string.find(subject.Name, 7) then
    inVal.Value = 7
elseif string.find(subject.Name, 8) then
    inVal.Value = 8
elseif string.find(subject.Name, 9) then
    inVal.Value = 9
end


You can parse the int value from the string using
string.match and then use tonumber function on it.
This would be more efficient then looping every possible answer.
local match = string.match(subject.Name, "%d")
inVal.Value = tonumber(match)


I've no idea how this works... But it works so well. I'm going to look into this, thanks!
Edit: After a few minutes of searching, the Lua Handbook and a forum post explained this pretty well. I'll be making sure to use this!

You can use a for loop and then use the loop's index to reduce your code down to only six lines.
In the below script, we iterate over subject.Name and see if index, a number, is in the subject.Name and then set the inVal.Value if it matches.
for index: number = 0, 9 do
    if string.find(subject.Name, tostring(index)) then
        inVal.Value = index
        break
    end
end

